# Jquery field clear

Tags: jquery, html

All,

I have a text area field in my for,.How do i clear contents of it on sum onclick using jquery

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('textarea').focus(function() {
  $(this).val('');
});
```

This will clear the textarea on focus (using mouse click or keyboard).

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#textArea").click(function(){ $(this).attr({ value: '' }); });
```

With a couple of caveats:

- it'll clear whenever someone clicks on it, even if they've entered data already
- it'll only work if someone clicks on the field

Comment: Alternatively, `$(this).val("")`.

Comment: `$(this).attr({ value: '' });` can also be expressed as `$(this).val('')`.

Answer (score 2):

This will clear the default value onclick and restore back onblur.

```
$('textarea').click(function () {
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {
        this.value = '';
    }
});
$('textarea').blur(function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
});
```